# Majorana fermions and the continuum limit of the Ising model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, fermions, ising-model, majorana-fermions

In [Paolo Moligini's *Analyzing the two dimensional Ising model with conformal field theory*](https://www1.ethz.ch/demoitp/education/fs13/cft/SM2_Molignini) lecture notes, it is shown at the end of chapter 3 that the Lagrangian of the continuum limit of the Ising model is given by:

$$ \mathcal{L}= \Psi^\dagger \partial_{\tau}  \Psi +
 \frac{v}{2}\left(\Psi^\dagger \partial_{x} \Psi^\dagger-\Psi \partial_x{\Psi}\right)+ \Delta \Psi^\dagger \Psi
$$

An he calls it a field theory of Majorana fermions of mass $\Delta/v^2$.

However, in section 4 it is said that the lagrangian of a free (massless, I think) Majorana fermion is

$$\mathcal{L}=
\frac{g}{2} \Psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \Psi 
$$

How can I see that this Lagrangians are equivalent?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: The second Lagrangian is for massless fermions, the first one for massive, with mass $\Delta$. If I choose $g=2$, $\gamma_{0}=1$, $\gamma_{\tau}=1$, $\gamma_{x}=v\sigma_{z}/2$ than I recover the first Lagrangian from the second one by adding the mass term. I have to equip the first $\Psi$ structure with a particle-hole symmetry to make the $\Psi\partial\Psi$ term also.